# Any tips on how to implement restrictions in a freemium app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, limit, cancan, restriction

I'm a struggling newbie to programming and trying to make a freemium style app with multiple plans available.

I'm using the cancan gem to assign venues a role depending on what plan they are on (free, premium, premium+).

I know how I can limit certain options being displayed in the views depending on which plan is assigned but how can I go about limiting number of records added to a venue depending on which plan is assigned?

e.g.

- I would like all venues to have photos but the free venues should be
  limited to just 3.
- I would also like all venues to have searchable tags but have the number of tags allowed change depending on which plan the venue is on.

Currently the plans are just specified in the venue model as:

```
PLANS = %w[free premium premium+]
```

**edit**

Thanks to the answer from Alex Peattie I think I'm on the right track now.

I changed the line `validate_on_create :photo_count_within_limit` to:

```
validate :venuephoto_count_within_limit, :on => :create
```

but am getting a ArgumentError in VenuesController#update: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed error.

**another edit**

So all is now well, just made these changes:

```
def photo_limit
  {:free => 3, :premium => 10}[plan.to_sym]
end
```

and

```
validate :venuephoto_count_within_limit, :on => :create
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Comment: Can't you achieve it through CanCan's ability as described here? https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd give the Venue model methods for `photo_limit`, `tag_limit` etc.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

  def photo_limit
    {:free => 3, :premium => 20, :"premium+" => 999}[plan]
  end

end
```

(this assumes a `.plan` method which will return the current Venue's plan)

Then use validations in Photo, like so:

```
class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base

  belong_to :venue
  validate_on_create :photo_count_within_limit

  def photo_count_within_limit
    if self.venue.photos(:reload).count >= self.venue.photo_limit
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded venue photo limit")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the speedy response thats exactly the kind of thing I'm after. I'm a little confused about the .plan method assumption though and am getting a no method error in the VenuesController#edit: `undefined method `validate_on_create' for`

Comment: I had assumed you'd be able to do something like `@my_venue.plan` and get "free" (or whatever) returned

Comment: I think validates_on_create has depreciated in rails 3, I changed the line to `validate :venuephoto_count_within_limit, :on => :create` but am now getting 'comparison of Fixnum with nil failed'.

Answer (score -1):

On my current project we have the same question. I haven't participate on that part, so i have no idea how it have been resolved. Maybe with some kind of global filter on the ApplicationController that checks for permissions on the current plan/subplan (yes, we have subplan too) of the user.

On monday i'll try to find some time to check how we implement this and answer you.

Comment: I'll do this evening. Hold on.